# Add a button inside a option

Tags: jquery, html

I want to add a button inside an option. Other optiones  are added dynamically from db  and one of other option acts like a button.

```
    <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-5 col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Gothra</label> <select id="gothra" name="gothra"
                        class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible"
                        style="width: 100%;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" >

                        <option selected="selected" value="">--Select--</option>
                            <%
                                for (int i = 0; i < gothralist.size(); i++) {
                            %>
                            <option value="<%=gothralist.get(i).getGothraId()%>"><%=gothralist.get(i).getGothra()%></option>
                            <%
                                }
                            %>  

                            <option value=""><button type="button" name="button" onclick="popupForAddGothrafn()">Other</button></option>
                    </select>
```

My sample code is pasted above. But it will not work properlly. After pressing that button, I want a popup window.
How is it possible?

Comment: Better onchange event display different button. You may alternatively try something using apperance: button; using CSS.

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest you to use **Bootstrap dropdown** to achieve such functionality. As far as I know it wont be possible to achieve this in native select component.

please use the [link](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp) to learn about it. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_dropdown-menu&stacked=h) is a working example of the same. You can add button in the bootstrap down like this -

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">other menu</a></li>
    <li><button class="btn btn-primary">Your Button</button></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad that it helped you. You can upvote or accept this ans which encourages me to write more of such ans :)

Comment: Here only works the button. Actually I want that button and some additional drop down lists. I want to choose that list also. Here only takes that button

Comment: I thought that's intuitive, I have updated the example to add other menu items along with the button. thanks :) I guess you unaccepted the answer.